Typescript error based on logical AND and OR check (defensive programming)
I'm learning typescript, type safety (defensive programming), and i'm trying to implement a linked list with typescript.
I don't understand why when I change the logical OR (||) to logical AND (&&) on if (!this.head || !this.tail) line, typescript throws an error on
const oldTail: NodeItem = this.tail; 
that:

Type 'NodeItem | null' is not assignable to type 'NodeItem'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'NodeItem'.


Main block:
 add(value: any): NodeItem {
    const newItem: NodeItem = { value: value, next: null };
    if (!this.head || !this.tail) {
      this.head = newItem;
      this.tail = this.head;
      this.total++;
      return newItem;
    }

    const oldTail: NodeItem = this.tail;
    this.tail = newItem;
    oldTail.next = this.tail;
    this.total = this.total++;

    return newItem;
  }


Entire code for context:
type NodeItem = {
  value: any;
  next: NodeItem | null;
};
class LinkedList {
  head: NodeItem | null = null;
  tail: NodeItem | null = null;
  total: number;

  constructor(value?: any) {
    value && this.add(value);
  }

  add(value: any): NodeItem {
    const newItem: NodeItem = { value: value, next: null };
    if (!this.head || !this.tail) {
      this.head = newItem;
      this.tail = this.head;
      this.total++;
      return newItem;
    }

    const oldTail: NodeItem = this.tail;
    this.tail = newItem;
    oldTail.next = this.tail;
    this.total = this.total++;

    return newItem;
  }

  print(): void {}
}


Because this.tail could be null in that case.

this happens because what if this.head is falsy? that will enter the if without asserting this.tail

Thanks @DanielA.White.
Do you mean when it's logical AND (if (!this.head && !this.tail))?
Becuase not sure that (this.head) when falsy (which results in !this.head truthy), would guarantee alone if the if executes or not, it also depends on the other express "!this.tail"?
Maybe im getting something wrong

Thanks @tkausl, after much reasoning, think i get you now... tho not fully explained, but thanks, loll

It's because after you change the logical OR (||) to logical AND (&&) on the if (!this.head || !this.tail) line, the if block is not executed.
this.tail is null, so !this.tail is false. Which means, for logical OR, the if block will be executed, changing this.tail's value to this.head's, and ensuring the error does not occur. But, for logical AND, the false means the block will not be executed, and so this.tail remains null, giving you the error.
Hope this was easy to understand!

Thank you, seems i got the reasoning wrong, it's clearer now...

So the logical OR(||) interprets as: if there is no head or there is no tail, always enter the if, and set tail = head. if there is tail, obviously tail cant be null hence no error.
But in the case of logical AND (&&), both of the evaluations (!this.head and !this.tail) has to be true for the if to run and set tail = head... So what if one of them is false, there is head but no tail, the tail would not be updated, hence could be null? and hence the error?
